# how do i create an array where each element in the array, of size 10, is pointing to an object, in C++?

Tags: c++

for example lets have a class or struct name Employee with two constructors, a default constructor and a constructor with parameters two strings and an int. why doesn't the following code work?

```
Employee *employees = (employee*) malloc(sizeof(Employee)*10);
```

let's say we have an array, size 10, of type string for first name, last name, and one of type int for salary. how to initialize the data members of each object class using the constructor with the parameters?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    employees[i] = employee(firstname[i], lastname[i], salary[i]);
}
```

I've been trying to do this for a few days now but wasn't successful. Also, can anyone tell how to do this using c++'s new and delete operator? and also is there a way this can be done using vectors?

Thank you

header file

```
class employee{

    std::string firstname;
    std::string lastname;
    int salary;


public:
    employee(std::string, std::string , int);
    employee();

    void setFirst(std::string);
    void setLast(std::string);
    void setSalary(int);

    std::string getFirst();
    std::string getLast();
    int getSalary();

};

employee::employee(std::string x, std::string y, int z)
{
    setFirst(x);
    setLast(y);
    setSalary(z);

}

void employee::setFirst(std::string x)
{
    firstname = x;
}

void employee::setLast(std::string y)
{
    lastname = y;
}
void employee::setSalary(int z)
{
    salary = z > 0 ? z : 0;
}

std::string employee::getFirst()
{
    return firstname;
}

std::string employee::getLast()
{
    return lastname;
}

int employee::getSalary()
{
    return salary;
}
```

.cpp file

```
#define MAX 20

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = 1;
    cout << "number of employees: ";
    cin >> n;

    string firstname[MAX];
    string lastname[MAX];
    double salary[MAX];

    float raise[MAX];


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Employee " << i + 1 <<endl;
        cout << "-----------\n";

        cout << "First Name: ";
        cin >> firstname[i];

        cout << "Last Name: ";
        cin >> lastname[i];

        cout << "Monthly Salary: ";
        cin >> salary[i];
        salary[i] *= 12;

        cout <<"Yearly percentage raise (e.g 10% or 0%): ";
        scanf("%f%%", &raise[i]);
        salary[i] *= (((raise[i])/100.00) + 1);

        puts("\n");

    }


    employee *employees = (employee*) malloc(sizeof(employee)*10);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        employees[i] = employee(firstname[i], lastname[i], salary[i]);
    }




    cout << "TESING USING GET FUNCTIONS" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Employee " <<i +1<< endl;
        cout <<"-----------\n";

        printf("First Name: %s", employees[i].getFirst().c_str());

        printf("\nLast Name: %s",employees[i].getLast().c_str());

        printf("\nYearly Salary: %d\n\n", employees[i].getSalary());
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you add Employee declaration ?

Comment: C doesn't use constructors as it is not object oriented, is this C or C++ (there is a difference, although you can make C code work in C++). If this is C++, use std::vector instead of arrays.

Comment: sorry, this is in c++

Comment: Please post this Employee class.  Once you post it, then you will get an answer (probably many) on why that malloc() call is a failure.

Comment: if you see a malloc in c++ you are almost certainly doing something against paradigm...

Comment: I don't know what you are doing but I suspect you should be doing either new  and sticking in a collection class or new[]

Comment: **Add the class declaration of `Employee`**.

Comment: @LezouDali - Well, look at my answer as to why using malloc() is a non-starter.

Comment: Don't forget the destructor and delete when using new, gotta clean up all of that memory you allocated with new (assuming you stick new in there and do it the C++ way)

Answer (score 1):

If this looks like your Employee class:

```
class Employee
{
   std::string first_name;
   std::string last_name;
   // other members and functions ...
};
```

Then using malloc() to create 10 of these is a complete and utter failure.  The reason why is that yes, you allocated memory using malloc(), but that's all you did.  You didn't *construct* 10 Employee objects.  Those std::string members need to be *constructed*, not merely have memory allocated.  So with that call to malloc() you have 10 fake Employees that were "created", and as soon as you attempt to do anything with one of them, then boom goes your program.

Do research on POD and non-POD types.  You cannot treat non-POD types (as the class above is non-POD) as you would a POD type.  For a non-POD type, the instance must be "officially" constructed, (the constructor must be invoked).

On the other hand, malloc() knows nothing concerning C++ and what is required to create an object correctly via construction.  All malloc (and calloc, and realloc) knows is to allocate bytes and return a pointer to the allocated space.

Comment: thank you so much, i just started programming for about 2 months now. thanks for the help

Comment: One thing -- I suggest you put down the 'C" books for a while (or stop looking at C code) and read C++ material.  I would be very surprised if you got the "malloc()" way of doing things from material dedicated to C++.

Comment: haha how did you know? i've teaching my c/c++ by going back and forth with books on c and c++. okay will do

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of Employee instances and Employee is not POD (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POD) you need to allocate memory from the stack using the operator new:

```
Employee* employees = new Employee[10];
```

And for having this working:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    employees[i] = Employee(firstname[i], lastname[i], age[i]);
}
```

you need to implement the operator= in your Employee class:

```
Employee& operator=(const Employee& src)
{
  _firstname = src._firstname;
  _lastname  = src._lastname;
  _age = src._age;
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: You create an array of 10 objects; OP specifically requested an array of 10 pointers to objects.   Of course, it's likely that your code is a better solution to the actual problem OP is working on, and he phrased his request badly.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I misunderstood the OP request because his declaration: Employee* employees;

Comment: thank you so much, i just started programming for about 2 months now. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a vector instead, it's resizable, it's easier to manage, and as Grady stated in his comment, it's also generally not good practice to use malloc in C++ code (although it's possible). Maybe do something that looks like this:

```
#include <vector>

...
int size = 10;

std::vector<Employee *> employees;

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    //as far as pulling in your data, that depends on where it's coming from
    Employee *temp = new Employee(...);
    employees.push_back(temp); 
}
```

I'm rusty on my C++ but this should work.

Comment: Though your code will work, you have to release the employee instances when getting out of the employees scope. I would suggest using stack based objects (i.e. vector<Employee> instead of vector<Employee*>) or using smart pointers to release the memory automatically (vector<shared_ptr<Employee>>)

Comment: Good point, yeah I'm pretty rusty on my C++ haven't written a full C++ program in going on about 8 years (working instead either in C or silly languages that do the releasing for you)

Comment: The difference between `vector<T>` and `vector<T*>` has nothing at all to do with "stack". The elements within a `vector<T>` are most likely to be allocated "on the heap".

Comment: One alternative is to declare the temp outside of the loop, use it to build the objects that get pushed onto the vector, and then use a delete after the loop to free up temp.

Comment: @Matt McNabb: Yes! You are correct! I meant "automatic" and I wrote "stack". Obviously it is not correct. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the refresher guys, I really should get back into writing C++ code

Comment: thank you so much, i just started programming for about 2 months now. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
#include <iostream>
class Employee
{
std::string m_firstname;
std::string m_lastname;
int m_age;
public:
Employee()
{
        m_firstname=m_lastname="";
        m_age=0;
}
void setFirstName(std::string firstname)
{
        m_firstname=firstname;
}
void setLastName(std::string lastname)
{
        m_lastname=lastname;
}
void setAge(int age)
{
        m_age=age;
}
void displayEmp()
{
        std::cout<<m_firstname;
        std::cout<<m_lastname;
        std::cout<<m_age;
}
};

int main()
{
std::string fname;
std::string lname;
int age;
Employee *employee = new Employee[10];
Employee *employeeptr=employee;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
        std::cin>>fname;
        std::cin>>lname;
        std::cin>>age;
        employeeptr->setFirstName(fname);
        employeeptr->setLastName(lname);
        employeeptr->setAge(age);
        employeeptr++;
}
employeeptr=employee;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
        employeeptr->displayEmp();
        employeeptr++;
}
delete []employee;
return 0;
}
```